# Turn off HDRI reflection

Tags: reflection

I try to turn off the reflections of the HDRI from the glass material.
With reflections the glass looks realistic, but when I add a node set-up to remove reflections that I found online, the glass looks wrong, it has gray color.

Any idea how to remove the reflections and still get the realistic glass as in image 1?[image]

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, if you remove the reflection the glass won't look good, maybe find another HDRI if you don't like this one?

Comment: @moonboots The issue I have is when creating a transparent background you can see the HDRI in the background in the upper part of image 1.